# Is it possible to put ios 10 on an ipod touch 4?

Tags: ios, ipod

I want to put ios 10 on my ipod touch 4 so that I can get the podcast app on it. Is this possible? How do I do that? I went into settings and saw if there was an update to ios and it says its up to date at ios 6

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

You can look on Wikipedia and see the oldest generation iPod that goes past iOS 9 is the 6th generation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Touch_(6th_generation)

See if your web browser can stream podcasts while you decide what to do. Apple support pages are a good resource as well for what hardware supports which iOS.